# Easy way to shorten up bind9 zone config?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, scripting, bind, cname-record

Is there an easy way to put some kind of variables into bind9 zone files?

Lets say i have a bunch of different zone-files, and i would like to define my ip's in one config file. So that i can make something like

www      A      $mywebserverip

I'm allready using CNAME records for this kind of things, but this is only working for subdomains, but not for the main domain's A records.

I'm more interested in some kind of script language that would generate the zone files for me and allow a single config place for ip-logic.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep all hostname -> IP mappings the same across zones, you can simply make all data in the zone file relative.

There are no built-in ways to script this, no.